# Equivalent goto statement in Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

Is there an equivalent Goto Statement in Salesforce? 
I need this to skip lot of lines of code from execution post a functional criteria is  mismatched . Currently i observe, my logic is able to show a custom exception on the Page, but code will still continue to execute lot of lines -which i would like to skip in case of failure and move directly to the end line of the code.
In such situation, i used to use goto statement in other languages but unable to find any replacement in salesforce. Please advice.

Comment: Are you trying to code BASIC in Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing from David's answers are alternative solutions to complicated if statements, which is usually why people resort to such things. One really nice trick that kind of simulates goto is a do-while loop. Simply, you can have your code execute once (and only once), but leave a way to get out of the entire block quickly without throwing an exception.

```
do {
  ... code ...
  if(condition1) {
    break;
  }
  ... more code ...
  if(condition2) {
    break;
  }
  ... even more code ...
} while(false);
```

The false value at the end forces the loop to run only once, but you get the convenience of multiple exit points that are arguably easier to read than severely nested if statements; it really feels like a goto, but without the associated traps.

Of course, if you have nested *loops*, that trick won't help you, as you can't skip back out an arbitrary number of levels... or can you?

```
Boolean break1 = false, break2;
for(Integer x = 0; !break1 && x < 10; x++) {
  break2 = false;
  for(Integer y = 0; !break2 && y < 10; y++) {
    for(Integer z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
      if(condition1) {
        break; // goto next y
      }
      if(condition2) {
        break2 = true;
        break; // goto next x
      }
      if(condition3) {
        break1 = true;
        break; // Exit all loops
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yes, it's slightly more code, but you can break out of any nested loop in a controlled manner with just a few simple Boolean variables. This makes the intent clear, unlike goto, which allows you to jump in from any arbitrary location.

And I can tell you, since I've started writing Apex Code, I can probably count the number of times I've used either technique on one paw, with a few digits left over. It's simply not necessary, because we have so many better tools at our disposal. Write more methods, and it becomes a matter of just writing "return" to break out of arbitrary groups of loops. Use classes to group bits of data and processing together.

Worst case scenario, just write a state machine and have it go from state to state. Technically, we use this "state machine" mechanism all the time. What do you think Visualforce controllers are? Exactly. Write a controller class, and call the methods on it as you need to, the class itself maintains state. In Java, it's very common to do this, but I think most Apex Code developers don't think of classes as much more than a place to store data and methods, rather than a complete machine by itself that can do incredibly complicated things.

Goto was from a time when compilers were simple and languages were simple, and it was really hard to get from point A to point B, so they needed a shortcut every once in a while. With a little bit more forethought, all code can be written in a way that never requires a goto.

Answer (score 4):

One really must lead with [Edsger Dijkstra](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)'s famous rant Go To Considered Harmful, even if it's a *little* extreme...

In all seriousness, Apex doesn't and shouldn't have `goto`. Any instance where you find yourself reaching for `goto` is a great impetus to refactor your code and make it more modular.

A very long method with complex, deeply nested logic and large numbers of statements in each branch of the code is not only difficult to understand, it is difficult to test. And as you probably know, testing is not optional in the Salesforce environment.

So there's two approaches you can take when the logical complexity of your code grows too high.

1. Refactor. Pull out units of functionality, even if they're not reusable outside the context of the current class, into separate methods, or even into utility classes. Not only does this reduce the complexity of each individual method, it also makes it possible for you to write meaningful unit tests for these modular code units. Refactoring effectively can reduce the total number of statements in a method, but can also reduce the logical depth and complexity by "hiding" some aspects of the decision making behind the veil of another method, or even another class entirely. It's a way to use abstraction to limit the net complexity of any single piece of code.
2. Use exceptions well. My philosophy on exceptions is that they should be just that (exceptional situations), not thrown on the drop of a hat - although some languages other than Apex do prescribe "common" exceptions. However, there *are* situations in real-world code where refactoring produces relatively little benefit; the logical depth remains very high, and, particularly, there is some manner of clean-up that needs to be executed regardless of the success or failure of the preceding statements and of which specific code path is executed.

   This is a great application for a `goto`-ish exception: dropping the entire method into a `try/catch` block keyed to catch your custom exception subclass only (*not* to simply swallow any exception that might take place, at least not unless you re-raise or otherwise handle underlying `QueryException` or `DMLException`s and so forth). You can throw that custom exception deep in your logic tree to "escape", so to speak.

   Your `catch (MyException e)`/`finally` clauses are a great place to handle any final clean-up that needs to take place in the method once you've escaped the logic tree, without multiplying `if` clauses checking for errors ad nauseum. That said, this is a tactic I would be relatively skeptical of because I think it is rarely justified.